# Interpreting some linear conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, graph-theory, linear-transformations

Let $K\geq 3$ and consider $K$ real numbers $\mu_1<\mu_2<...<\mu_K$.

Let $\delta_j\equiv \mu_{j+1}-\mu_j$ $\forall j \in \{1,...,K-1\}$.

For $h\in \{2,...,K-1\}$, consider the following set of conditions
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\delta_1+\delta_2+...+\delta_{h-3}+\delta_{h-2}+ \delta_{h-1}  \neq  \delta_{K-1},\\
&\delta_1+\delta_2+...+\delta_{h-3}+\delta_{h-2}\hspace{1.2cm}  \neq \delta_{K-1}+\delta_{K-2},\\
&\delta_1+\delta_2+...+\delta_{h-3}\hspace{2.4cm}  \neq \delta_{K-1}+\delta_{K-2}+\delta_{K-3},\\
&...\\
&\delta_1 \hspace{5.4cm}\neq \delta_{K-1}+\delta_{K-2}+\delta_{K-3}+...+\delta_{K-h-1}.
\end{aligned}
$$

For example, for $K=3$ we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\delta_1\neq \delta_2.
\end{aligned}
$$

For $K=4$ we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\delta_1\neq \delta_3,\\
& \delta_1+\delta_2 \neq \delta_3,\\
&\delta_1\neq \delta_3+\delta_2.
\end{aligned}
$$

For $K=5$ we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\delta_1\neq \delta_4,\\
& \delta_1+\delta_2 \neq \delta_4,\\
&\delta_1+\delta_2+\delta_3\neq \delta_4,\\
&\delta_1+\delta_2\neq \delta_4+\delta_3,\\
&\delta_1\neq \delta_4+\delta_3+ \delta_2,\\
& \delta_1\neq \delta_4+\delta_3\\
\end{aligned}
$$
I would like to know whether these conditions can be linked to some geometric/linear algebra/graph theory concept. Somehow, they rule out some specific linear combinations with a sort of geometric path, but if I was asked to explain the above conditions in English I would not be able to do so. Could you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$\sum_{j=m}^n\delta_j = \mu_{n+1} -\mu_m,$$
since the middle terms cancel. We can then rewrite a condition 
$$\delta_1+\dots+\delta_h\neq \delta_i+\dots+\delta_{K-1}$$
with $1\leq h<i\leq K-1 $ as
$$\mu_{h+1} - \mu_1 \neq\mu_K-\mu_i.$$
Rearranging yields that the sum of the first and last $\mu$ is different from the sum of any other pair of $\mu$'s (since $h$ and $i$ can be chosen arbitrarily), and different from any other $\mu$ doubled (take $h=i-1$).

This is a massive simplification IMO, but I don't know where this sort of thing would arise.

Comment: Thanks. Note that $\sum_{j=m}^n \delta_j=\mu_{n+1}-\mu_m$. Does this change your conclusions?

Comment: Just taking your answer it looks like that my condition can be rewritten as: for $h=1,...,K-2$ and for $i=2,...,K-1$, $\mu_{h+1}-\mu_1\neq \mu_K-\mu_i$. Correct? Does this way of rewriting rings any bell of theorems, notions of graph theory, etc?

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify whether your answer should be interpreted as: my condition is equivalent to $\mu_{h+1}-\mu_1\neq \mu_K-\mu_i$ for each $h,i$ such that $1\leq h<i\leq K-1$?

Comment: I recalculated, and I think this should be correct now. This kind of index juggling can be a bit error prone. I think your second to last calculation is correct. We can get around the $h<i$ with a bit of regrouping. I'll try to think of any bells this might ring, but I don't see anything now.

Answer (score 1):

[Adloggan's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3432939/2643) has the arithmetic of the situation. So, here's one possible intuitive interpretation. Imagine a stick of length $\mu_K - \mu_1$ with notches carved into it at intervals representing $\mu_j$ in the natural way. Then, the set of inequalities imply that the stick cannot be broken along those notches into $>1$ pieces so that the leftmost piece has the same length as the rightmost piece.